# Logic validate angular, javascript

Tags: javascript, angular

```
<input onkeydown="javascript: return event.keyCode === 8 || event.keyCode === 46 ? true : (!isNaN(Number(event.key)) [(ngModel)]="pageInput"/>
```

I have input that validates the value when the user enters data, my current logic of `onkeydown` above is not allowing the user to write down non-numeric characters!

Here is the code which I validate `(!isNaN(Number(event.key))`

Could you guys help me to add more logic to this `(!isNaN(Number(event.key))`

I have `{{totalpages}}` that I want User just only write down only the number which `> 0 and >= {{totalpages}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

handle the keydown event in angular like this:

```
(keydown)="onKeyDown($event)"
```

then put this in your ts controller:

```
onKeyDown(event) {
   // whatever keydown logic you would like in here
}
```